# Google Earth not install on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, google-earth

I'm trying to install Google Earth on Ubuntu 14.04 and get the following error. The problem show up using **dpkg -i** to install the .deb downloades from Google site, beside I tested with **Ubuntu Software Center** too.

Exists similar questions in this site talking about installation problems, but none of them are on 14.04, so I decided post a new questions seeking for tips-solutions for the current LTS Ubuntu version (most comments and suggestion in those previous questions are targeted oldest Ubuntu versions)

```
Preparing to unpack google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-earth-stable (7.1.2.2041-r0) ... dpkg: dependency
problems prevent configuration of google-earth-stable: 
google-earth-stable depends on lsb-core (>= 3.2); however:   Package
lsb-core is not installed.  google-earth-stable depends on ia32-libs;
however:   Package ia32-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-earth-stable (--install): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Processing triggers for
man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ... Processing triggers for bamfdaemon
(0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ... Rebuilding
/usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index... Processing triggers for
gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ... Processing triggers for
desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for
mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ... Errors were encountered while
processing:  google-earth-stable
```

Doing what is described [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/install-google-earth-in-ubuntu-1404.html) I got:

```
sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb  Selecting
previously unselected package google-earth-stable. (Reading database
... 277661 files and directories currently installed.) Preparing to
unpack google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb ... Unpacking
google-earth-stable (7.1.2.2041-r0) ... dpkg: dependency problems
prevent configuration of google-earth-stable:  google-earth-stable
depends on lsb-core (>= 3.2); however:   Package lsb-core is not
installed.  google-earth-stable depends on ia32-libs; however:  
Package ia32-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package google-earth-stable (--install): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Processing triggers for
man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ... Processing triggers for bamfdaemon
(0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ... Rebuilding
/usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index... Processing triggers for
gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ... Processing triggers for
desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ... Processing triggers for
mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ... Errors were encountered while
processing:  google-earth-stable
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try the method given [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/04/install-google-earth-in-ubuntu-1404.html) to install Google earth

The problem with Google Earth is that the 32bit package doesn't support multiarch so it doesn't install all the 32bit dependencies it needs to run on Ubuntu 64bit.

I recommend you just copy paste the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libxext6:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386; cd /tmp && wget http://dl.google.com/dl/earth/client/current/google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb; sudo dpkg -i google-earth-stable_current_i386.deb; sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then download and install 32 bit software package on 64 bit system.

Answer (score 3):

This works for kubuntu **14.04** **AMD64** on my system

1. Download the 32bit package (trust me the amd64 bit package is NOT
   truly 100% 64bit -shame on google, how long has 64bit been around?)
2. Install the google .deb package
3. Open a terminal and run the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 libglib2.0-0:i386 libsm6:i386 libglu1-mesa:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libxext6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libx11-6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 lsb-core
   ```
4. Thats it, now it should run without errors From the command line,
   run `google-earth`

**Reference:** [GoogleEarth](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GoogleEarth)

Comment: I used the file command on the googleearth-bin file from the 64 bit package and it turns out that it's a 64-bit executable what do you mean by it's not a 100% 64 bit what trick they're using???

Comment: Thank you, after installing those packages Google Earth installed just fine on Kubuntu 14.10 for me.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that ia32-libs (which Google Earth wants) doesn't exist any more. However it has been replaced!
This worked for me (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS,installing google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb):

Open a terminal window and copy-paste:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0
```

After doing this google-earth-stable_current_amd64.deb will be installed without any errors.

Comment: didn't work, and I don't see why it would. The package requires the dependency to ia32-libs package. If you don't have it, it'll fail installation.

Answer (score 2):

I am an Ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit user. I spent about more than 2 days in the internet to get a solution for this issue. I tried almost all of the given suggestions, including Webupd8's solution, but could not reach a solution.

I finally found the below solution, and now Google Earth working flawlessly in my PC. Now I can search in Google Earth with no problem, and I do not even face the "blank image frame" problem.

**Solution:**

1. Uninstall previous Google Earth versions. I used Synaptic Package Manager to uninstall Google Earth.
2. Install `ia32-libs`:

   ```
   sudo -i
   cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d
   echo "deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse" >ia32-libs-raring.list
   apt-get update
   apt-get install ia32-libs
   ```

   P.S: At the end, you may remove the `ia32-libs-raring.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`, then update the system by typing `sudo apt-get update` command.
3. Then go to [Mint's link](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/import/g/googleearth/) and download the `googleearth_6.2.2.6613-r0_i386.deb` version and install it from the terminal by typing:

   ```
   sudo gdebi googleearth_6.2.2.6613-r0_i386.deb
   ```
4. After finishing the installation, run this command: `google-earth` .
5. After you run the Google Earth and search for a certain city in the Search Box, and face a problem such: `invalid HTTP request` then proceed below in a termial:

   ```
   sudo mv /opt/google/earth/free/libcurl.so.4 /opt/google/earth/free/backup_libcurl.so.4
   ```

Google Earth should work correctly, it did work in my PC like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 (64bit) and had the same problem. The 32 bit version of GE worked for me to some extent, but the panaramo images wouldn't load in GE. I found the answer here worked for me to get the 64 bit one working (amongst other things, you remove the dependancy line): https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/maps/_h4t6SpY_II/xK1umdGFykAJ

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using doing this

[Google Earth Install x64 on Linux Mint 18 Cin](https://askubuntu.com/q/905968/571613)

After I solved it, I broke out in dance to Prince's song "Kiss"