# Google Earth Installation x64 (Xenial) lsb-core

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, google-earth

## Google Earth x86 64 bit Architecture Installation Troubleshoot

```
depends on lsb-core (>= 3.2)
```

If you had these issues

```
Package lsb-core is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

after running this

```
sudo apt-get install lsb-core
[sudo] password for 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

E: Package 'lsb-core' has no installation candidate
```

Or this

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lsb-core : Depends: alien (>= 8.36) but it is not going to be installed
```

And have tried these resources to no avail.

- [sudo apt-get install lsb-core -y -f](https://apipeandakeyboard.com/2016/07/03/install-google-earth-with-photos-on-linux-mint-18-64bit/)
- [“Dependency is not satisfiable:lsb core (>=3.0)” while downloading Hamachi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456749/google-earth-not-install-on-14-04)
- [Anybody able to get Google Earth working on 17.x? SOLVED](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456749/google-earth-not-install-on-14-04)
- [How to install Google-Earth 64bit in Ubuntu 13.10, ia32-libs Dependency error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366438/how-to-install-google-earth-64bit-in-ubuntu-13-10-ia32-libs-dependency-error)

I have a solution below that worked for me and I hope it works for you.

Comment: I removed the reference to Linux Mint (which is normally off topic here) because I believe that the issue would be identical in Ubuntu.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks David. Only reason, I brought that up was this `Now that Mint 18 has been released, the first thing I noticed was that Google Earth is not available in the repositories and requires a manual download and install' - [(https://apipeandakeyboard.com/2016/07/03/install-google-earth-with-photos-on-linux-mint-18-64bit/)]

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to clarify how *exactly* you tried to install Google Earth as well as the *full, verbatim* output of all commands that led to warning or error messages? I know you answered your own question but it would be more useful if future readers could retrace and compare the original issue. I also believe that I can come up with a simpler, less convoluted answer if I knew more about the original situation. Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm this problem does happen on Ubuntu, and not just Mint.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I unfortunately, do not have all of the code that I entered because I killed the terminal after posting here, but was able to go back and grab some links that I used. Someone who has this issue, hopefully will see this, and hopefully it helps them.

Comment: @DavidFoerster better?

Comment: Thanks but I don't think it's enough. You have (had) some underlying package management problem unrelated to Google Earth (see my comment on your answer for details). Since you resolved them it's hard to trace back to the original issue. I'm voting to close this question as unclear despite the known "solution" because it lacks information that would make it reproducible and useful for other readers.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Who are you to decide whether or not my information is  helpful? Wouldn't users who use this platform be able to vote on that? I do not think you saying "I do not think it's enough" is justified to close the question. 'I also believe that I can come up with a simpler, less convoluted answer if I knew more about the original situation' Is that a polite way of not wanting me to post or just a blatant "fuck you." Maybe what I posted is not a 'solution', you may be right, I may had an underlying package mgt issue,  but that does not justify this not being able to help someone else.

Comment: I'm sorry if I came off too rejecting without offering a good rationale. On AskUbuntu we value questions as long as the community (represented by its reviewers) agrees that they hold value for future readers which is not the case with an unclear question and a self-posted answer that doesn't really show what caused the issue or provide reasonable grounds to expect that the same answer is likely going to help other people with a similar issue. I offered my opinion so that both you and other reviewers may understand it.

Answer (score 0):

## SHORTCUT

- Make sure you do not have any version of Google Earth on your system

  `sudo apt-get purge google-earth-stable`
- Have aptitude installed

  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install aptitude

**Download the latest version of Google Earth**
[Select .64 bit deb file and Hit Agree and Download](https://www.google.com/earth/download/ge/agree.html)

[image: Select .64 bit deb file]

- Run

  sudo aptitude -f install lsb-core

## Downgrade your system by hitting 'n', then 'y', 'y

- see further down for exact details of specific output

Then run
    sudo dpkg -i "NAMEOFYOURDEB.deb"

To install all necessary packages for it. It will tell you if you need to install something else.

Finally finish installing it by running

```
sudo gdebi "name_of_your_current_release".deb
```

"only use sudo if not root"

### LONGER EXPLANATION

**Assumptions of what I had installed on my machine and am assuming you have on yours:**

- I had aptitude installed.
- I did not google-earth on my system. It was
  completely removed.
- I downloaded a current stable .deb file on my system

### Only Run Commands Below this Line After Reading Below

- I then ran
   sudo dpkg -i google-earth-pro-stable_current_amd64.deb 
  which satisfies all the package dependencies for it.
- I then ran

  sudo gdebi "name_of_your_current_release".deb

*You should see Google Earth in Menu Bar when you search "google earth"*

### ______READ____ME_____FIRST____________

### **These are the Steps to follow for downgrading.**

1. I downgraded my system because in order to run google earth they require you to have lib-core and that apparently is not supported anymore so run
   sudo aptitude -f install lsb-core
2. Then you would enter No, when first asked and then you would enter Yes.

   - The reason why, you would enter no first is because if you respond 'no', it would simply not change anything and you will still get the 'lsb-core' error

> The following NEW packages will be installed:   alien{a} at{a}
>   lib32z1{a} librpmbuild3{a} librpmsign1{a} lsb-core pax{a} rpm{ab}  0
>   packages upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
>   Need to get 493 kB of archives. After unpacking 1,611 kB will be used.
>   The following packages have unmet dependencies: rpm : Depends: rpm-common (= 4.10.1-2.1ubuntu1) but 4.12.0.1+dfsg1-3build3 is installed. The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

```
 Keep the following packages at their current version:
 1)alien [Not Installed] 
 2)lsb-core[Not Installed]
 3) rpm [Not Installed]
```

**Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n**

> The following actions will resolve
>   these dependencies:
>
> ```
>  Downgrade the following packages:                                         1)     rpm-common [4.12.0.1+dfsg1-3build3 (now) -> 4.10.1-2.1ubuntu1
> ```
>
> (raring)] 2)     rpm2cpio [4.12.0.1+dfsg1-3build3 (now) ->
>   4.10.1-2.1ubuntu1 (raring)]
>
> **Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y**
>
> The following packages will be
>   DOWNGRADED:   rpm-common rpm2cpio  The following NEW packages will be
>   installed:   alien{a} at{a} lib32z1{a} librpmbuild3{a} librpmsign1{a}
>   lsb-core pax{a} rpm{a}  0 packages upgraded, 8 newly installed, 2
>   downgraded, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded. Need to get 523 kB of
>   archives. After unpacking 1,696 kB will be used.
>
> **Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y**

Comment: Even though this worked for you the issue was likely unrelated to Google Earth and more related to some other package(s) blocking the installation of `lsb-core`. My guess it that `aptitude install -f lsb-core` suggested a solution that somehow didn't involve the removal of `ubuntu-desktop` & Co. Unfortunately it's hard to tell in retrospective.